# Why and how to convert file into a base64 string

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64

I am using React Native to send a post request to an endpoint. In this post request, one of the params has to be a file. Can I set the param to the direct image selected from the camera roll, or turn it into a string first, using a base64 string?

Answer (score 0):

You can covert any image into base64 using package called imageStore which comes from react-native

```
ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(uri,success=>{
//do something with your image's base64
},failure=>{
//handle error
})
```

pass uri which you get from cameraRoll

Comment: Oh nice thank you man. I am uploading an image to amazon s3 server. When sending it as a parameter in the http request, should i directly set the param to the file from the camera roll, or convert it into a base64 ?

Comment: convert to base64